# Max and min in nupmy written laconic

Tags: numpy, vector, max, min

What I want to achieve in Numpy:

```
tmp = 10 - y * (X @ w) #some complex expression
m = np.max(np.vstack([np.ones(tmp.shape), tmp]), axis=0)
```

Do I can write this in one line?
Something like

```
1 Max (10 - y * (X @ w))
```

I think it is essential to write math formulas as laconic as possible.

Comment: The general idea in programming is to write math formula as **obvious** as possible. The first snippet of code I can google.

Comment: Imagine you have pages of such code with HUGE formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first example is unnecessary complex, because you're doing a lot of work to broadcast `1` to `tmp.shape`. But I think `np.maximum` will automatically broadcast that - which also removes the need to `vstack` and select the stacking axis.

Comment: Super, thanks! Hadn't noticed np.maximum.